# TI-84 Plus CE gcd of every element in list L1

Tags: greatest-common-divisor, texas-instruments

I have a list in L1 and I would need help finding the greatest common divider of every element. The list has a variable length(size?).
An example:

| L1 |
| --- |
| 18 |
| 24 |
| 36 |

should return 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should work as a program. Basically the calculator has a built-in gcd() function, but it only works on two numbers at a time.

So what we're doing here is cycling through the list and gcd'ing our previous gcd with the next number.

```
:L1(1)->D
:For(X,1,dim(L1))
:gcd(D,L1(x))->D
:End
:Disp D
```